# Bootstrap hyperlink in navbar dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navbar

Hyperlink in navbar dropdown doesn't seem to work.Even the **"disabled"** doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle disabled"
           data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://www.google.com"> Link
            <b class="caret"></b> </a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li></ul>
        </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the link where you have set Google as the link won't take you to that link as the click action on that link opens/closes the dropdown menu.

If you put a link on another anchor tag you'll see that those will work fine.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that?